# How to dismiss keyboard from UITextview defined in UITableview for IPad

Tags: ipad

I am new to iPad programming, I want to know how to dismiss the keyboard from UItextview which is defined in UItablecell. I have multiple textviews defined in cell. Kindly help me out with a proper solution or suggestion from your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the text view the message `resignFirstResponder` and the keyboard will dismiss. If you need to have it dismiss in response to the return key, look at having your view controller adopt the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol.

```
[self.textViewInQuestion resignFirstResponder];
```

Alternatively, you can send the `endEditing:` message to the table view like this:

```
/*
  Attempt to resign first responder status on any textfields within 
  the view's hierarchy.
*/

[self.tableView endEditing:NO];


// OR we can....


/*
  Force text fields within the view's hierarchy to resign first responder.
  Textfield delegates cannot prevent this from happening so this is not 
  recommended if you need to perform field validation and prevent the user 
  from leaving the textfield.

  However sometimes it is useful to be able to force the resignation of the 
  first responder status even with validation so it goes both ways really.
*/

[self.tableView endEditing:YES];
```